# Two std::shared_ptr Runtime Error

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does the following code produce a SIGABRT? I thought this was the whole idea behind shared_ptr, is that you can share ownership.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
void func1()
{
  int* i = new int ( 10 );
  std::shared_ptr<int> sp1 (i);
  std::shared_ptr<int> sp2 (i);
}

int main()
{
  func1();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have two *different* shared pointers, each with its own reference counter, but pointing to the same data.

That means that both will try to delete the same pointer.

You should initialize the second pointer with the first:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp1(new int[10]);
std::shared_ptr<int> sp2 = sp1;
```

Now both shared pointers are truly shared.

Comment: So why does `std::shared_ptr<int> sp2 = std::make_shared<int>(sp1);` not work either?

Comment: @wizurd Because it still makes a new unique "shared" pointer, so you still have two different shared pointers to the same object, each with its own reference counter.